# R:Run randomly any of four lines /commands

Tags: r

I have 4 differents lines/commands (the addition is just an example)

```
one<- (1+1)
two<- (2+2)
three<-(3+3)
four<-(4+4)
```

I need to run randomly any of this four command lines (one, two, three or four), I am no focus in the addition result.

I did try  with:

```
list=c("one", "two", "three", "four")
number <- sample(list, 1)
number
```

but lamentably didnt run the line/command.

I expect that the sampling can run on the console any of these 4 commands.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try removing the `"` when you define `list`?

Comment: What's wrong with `F <- function(x) { x+x }; F(sample(1:4, 1))`?

Comment: Because you put the words in quotes, your list is just a vector containing the words "one", "two", "three", and "four". As Mike H said, remove the quotes to use the objects that you defined earlier.

Comment: @Cpak I don't use a function because  I need call and run the command, don't just get the result.

Comment: Perhaps this example doesn't capture exactly what you are trying to do. Once the line `one <- (1+1)` is run, `one` becomes 2 and doesn't remember it used to be `1+1` later. You can't delay evaluation this way.

Comment: @MrFlick you are right I will set my ask

Comment: @divibisan and Mike H. removing the quotes lamentably don't work

Comment: `get(number)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like maybe the problem is that you aren't constructing the list correctly?  Does this do what you expect?

```
one <-   (1+1)
two <-   (2+2)
three <- (3+3)
four <-  (4+4)
myList <- list(one, two, three, four)
number <- sample(myList, 1)[[1]]
```

Comment: I expect that run any of these four commands, not that give me the result of addition.

Comment: number
[1] 6
I don't need a number result I need to run any of 4 lines

Answer (score 0):

Because `(1 + 1)` evaluated to `2` and that `2` is assigned to `one`, it is impossible to retrieve `(1 + 1)` through `one` (if you define it the way you did). If you want to capture `1 + 1`, etc, you can do the following:

```
one = quote(1 + 1)
two = quote(2 + 2)
three = quote(3 + 3)
ls = list(one, two, three)
x = sample(ls, 1)[[1]]
x  # expression like 1 + 1
eval(x)  # evaluated sum
```

Comment: @Thanks Jordi for your answer,  I did change my ask to explain better my question.

Comment: Depending on your final goal, perhaps you are better off simply using characters like `one = "1 + 1"`.